# Как с помощью функций foreach и glob пройти по всем подпапкам и подключить все php файлы?

Tags: php

Есть папка src, в которой лежат php скрипты и папка Google. В папке Google лежат php скрипты и еще множество подпапок с PHP скриптами. Как с помощью функций foreach и glob пройти по всем подпапкам и подключить все php файлы?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно, но вряд ли нужно... обычно.
А обойти можно рекурсией, мой друг:

```
<?
function incl($path){
    foreach(glob($path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '*') as $val){
        if(is_dir($val))
            incl($val);
        else
            if(preg_match('/\.(?:php|phtml|phps)$/', $val)){
                // Тут делать что-то с PHP-файлом, например require_once $val
            }
    }
}

incl(__DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'src');
```